# Merging two similar records in powerApps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-collection, powerapps-selected-items

I've a collection as shown in the Image:

[image]

Now i have to merge both Sharepoint;Nintex and Nintex;Sharepoint into one record in final collection i.e as SharePoint;Nintex by removing the duplicate Nintex;SharePoint one